# Store a data frame into dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

There are multiple data frames in the dataset I have. How to store the data frame "null data" into a different dataset?

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous. If you want to get help you have to be more specific. Try to add an example for it.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.